# Comparing two columns and highlighting the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA to compare AB and AE Column and check if the AB column contains the value as "High" then the corresponding AE column should not contain the date which is less than current date - 10 months otherwise the cell should be highlighted in red. I tried the below code but it is highlighting all the date values.

```
Dim High As Range
Dim StartDate As Date
For Each High In Range("AB:AB")
    If High.Value = "High" Then
        If Not IsDate(Range("AE" & High.Row) = StartDate - 300) Then
            Range("AE" & High.Row).Interior.Color = 255
        End If
    End If
Next High
```

Comment: Use conditional formatting instead of VBA for this!

Comment: could you please help me to develop macro, this is part of my macro

Comment: No, you don't need a macro you just need conditional formatting. No VBA no macro is needed.

Comment: Pᴇʜ you don't know that, we don't know if this is part of a bigger project or what OP is finally trying to accomplish.. VBA may very well be what he needs instead of CF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Pᴇʜ has already mentioned, you could accomplish this by using conditional formatting. However, if you want to colour the cells once, statically, edit your code to the following:

```
Dim High As Range
Dim StartDate As Date

StartDate = Date

With Workbooks(REF).Sheets(REF) 'Add correct references

LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
For Each High In .Range("AB2:AB" & LRow) 'Assuming you have a header row
    If High.Value = "High" Then
        If IsDate(.Range("AE" & High.Row)) = False Then 
            .Range("AE" & High.Row).Interior.Color = vbRed
        Else
            If DateValue(.Range("AE" & High.Row)) < StartDate -300  Then .Range("AE" & High.Row).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    End If
Next High

End With
```

Comment: Thanks Tim it is working fine, only problem here is it is not highlighting the cells in AE column which is not in date format(DD/MM/YYYY)

Comment: The way I understand from your post is that you want the cells highlighted in red which store a date prior to 10 months back relative to today. Tell me what it is you want to achieve

Comment: I want the cells to be highlighted in red which store a date prior to 10 months back relative to today and also the cells to be highlighted in red if there any value which is not in dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: No problem. In that case, don't forget to accept my answer!

Answer (score 0):

The code uses the OPs "Not IsDate(), removes the extra IFs using And/Or, using Offset assigns the second cell as a variable, and colors both cells at the same time using the cell variables and .address.

Dim sDate As Date, cel As Range, cel2 As Range
sDate = Date

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'loop through each cell in range, does not use lRow variable
    For Each cel In .Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        Set cel2 = cel.Offset(, 4) 'Set the second cell variable to column E using offset

        'Use And/Or in the IF statement to test the values in the ranges
        If cel.Value = "High" And (Not IsDate(cel2) Or cel2 < sDate - 300) Then
            'Set both cells color at the same time using the cell address for both variables
            Range(cel.Address & "," & cel2.Address).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next cel
End With
```